# how to get records which id greter than some date like using linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

i need to fetch the date which is newer then 23/03/2018.

code

```
List<MDetails> Pirs = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MDetails>>(responseString);

Pirs = Pirs.OrderByDescending(x => (x.timestamp)).Take(100).ToList();
Pirs = Pirs.Where(x => (x.updatedate > 22/03/2018));

//datatype
public class MDetails
    {
        public DateTime timestamp { get; set; }
        public string dataFrame { get; set; }
        public double filled { get; set; }
        public DateTime updatedate { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: First I would suggest to read the IntelliSense error. Because `x.updatedate > 22/03/2018)` is clearly a _"Cannot apply Operator '>' to operands of type DateTime and Int"_. Then please read any C# book to understand whats Type are. IntelliSense is clearly stating that x.updatedate is a DateTime. But How could 22/03/2018 be a Int? Perhaps that's your issue.. You can parse it to a DateTime..

Comment: And btw you took 100 before filtering with the where clause thats mean that you will have from 0 to 100 results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

22/03/2018 will result in 0,0036339610175091 :-)

`x.updatedate > 22/03/2018` should be

`x.updatedate > new DateTime(2018, 03, 22)` or if you want to ignore the timecomponent use

`x.updatedate.Date > new DateTime(2018, 03, 22)`

If you think of performance you may extract the `new DateTime()` from the linq-expression to a local variable.

Combining the 2 queries could be done like

`Pirs = Pirs.OrderByDescending(x => (x.timestamp)).Take(100).Where(x => x.updatedate > new DateTime(2018, 03, 22)));`

Comment: saying convert string to long

Comment: Even so, I think you should note in your answer that a date like 22/03/2018 00:00:01  is bigger than a date 22/03/2018 00:00:00 produced by new DateTime(2018, 3, 22)

Comment: I changed the answer

Comment: Pirs = Pirs.OrderByDescending(x => (x.timestamp)).Take(100).ToList();
                    Pirs = Pirs.Where(x=> x.timestamp.Date > new DateTime(2018, 03, 22)).ToList();

how to combine both this statements

Comment: @KrishnaMohan: I added it to the answer.